# form is not submit when click on submit button of ajax response HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used jquery for ajax call in php and I got proper result for the same, but in   result's (response) HTML I have one form which is not submitting after click on submit button. I did not get any error for the same.
Also I want to submit this response HTML form without using Ajax.
Please help me for this issue.

Ajax Response:

```
<form method=\"post\" id=\"clientlist\" action=\"addclients.php\">
  //inputs fileds...
</form>
```

Ajax Call:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
   $j(".linktext").click(function(){ 

   //check which link is tobe click e.g. Prev or Next
   var link = $j(this).html();
   var limit = 1;
   if(link == 'Prev'){
     limit = document.getElementById('text_prev').value;
   }else if(link =='Next'){ 
     limit = document.getElementById('text_next').value;
   }

   $j.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $j("#clientlist").serialize(),
     url: "agencyclients_ajax.php?start="+limit,
     success: function(response) {
       $j('#mainbody').html(response);
     }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Maybe you should use preventDefault() method to prevent form from submitting. If you don't want to use ajax, than use regular PHP. Or am I missing something?

Comment: could you share some more code? more specifically, the AJAX call that actually gets the new form and HTML that is presented on page before the new form lands there would help

Answer (score 0):

Please Use SUBMIT Event for the form.
When You click on submit just do the ajax call and then return false to make sure that form is not submitted in a normal manner.

Right now you are using link CLICK Event `//not encouraged.`

And for jquery no conflict, Use this code:

```
(function($){
   $(function(){
      //$ can be used in this area without any conflict, provided by jQuery Docs for creating a plugin
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the ajax response to:

```
<form method="post" id="clientlist" action="addclients.php">
  //inputs fileds...
</form>
```

Remove the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event handler isn't added to '.linktext' after it is reloaded.

You can use the JQuery On function so that the event handler is reapplied when the DOM changed.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$j(".linktext").click(function(){
```

becomes

```
$j(".linktext").on("click", function(event){
```

Comment: the op asked `I want to submit this response HTML form without using Ajax` so i dont think this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  Replace $('#submit') with your submit button id.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url: '/search.php',
         data: $j("#clientlist").serialize(),
         success: function(data){
            alert('sent');
         }
     });
return false;
});
```